# Using a different coordinate scale with Android SDK [JAVA]

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, coordinates

I'm currently creating an application that requires me to refer to coordinates such as (1000,1500) on a bitmap image that is only (100,100), so I have thought of using y = 1000 as the origin instead of 0 and y = 2000 instead of 100, I have looked at lots of articles and questions on different websites but have not come across a way of doing so. I apologise for not being able to show any code that I have done right now but I'm wondering if anybody has any ideas on how to go about doing this.

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the easiest way to do this would just be to resize the bitmap. I'm not really sure what you're talking about with the origin thing, but it would be easy to make the bitmap 1500 x 1500 instead of 100 x 100. If that isn't an option, please explain what you are trying to use to make the application